# Javascript regex : replace more than one forward slashes with only one slash

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have file names of the following form : /folder/file.jpg that I want to sanitize by removing any extra forward slashes.

e.g :

```
'/tt////Images/WP1213.jpg' => '/tt/Images/WP1213.jpg' (example 1)

'///tt/Images/WP1213.jpg' => '/Images/WP1213.jpg'     (example 2)
```

I have used the following regex : `myString.replace(/\/+/, "/")`
However, this doesn't work with example 1, it only works with example 2.

how do I write a regex that captures example 2 as well ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slash and also you must add global modifier (`g`), so that the replacement would occur globally or otherwise it would replaces the first match only.

```
myString.replace(/\/+/g, "/")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yP3iB0/19)

Answer (score 2):

"More than one" is `{2,}` in the regex language:

```
myString.replace(/\/{2,}/g, "/");
```

http://regex101.com/r/qO5aO5/1

`\/+` is less efficient since it also "replaces" single slashes.

Comment: I understand your reasoning, and have up-voted, but have you run a perf to support your assertion?